# mysqldump: unknown option '--performance schema' error

Tags: mysql

When i tried to used mysqldump command on Linux, even for help `mysqldump --help`, returns the error `mysqldump: unknown option '--performance schema'` on cammand line. 
   Please tell me the reason causing this error.

Comment: The only way to cause that error is by running `mysqldump` with the option "performance schema" i.e. `mysqldump --performance\ schema` or `mysqldump "--performance schema"`.  Check what `mysqldump` script is being executed: `which mysqldump`. Perhaps you have a "proxy" or "shim" script called `mysqldump` which is then calling `mysqldump` with the "performance schema" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `--no-defaults` in mysqldump command. For example, for help it will be `mysqldump --no-defaults --help`, then it will display the help. `--no-defaults` can be used to prevent the unknown options from being read.

For more information, please enter `man mysqldump` in command line.